# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^na(2^n)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ be a series such that $(a(n))$ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^na(2^n)$ converges.